# How to copy xml tag by it's attribute name value

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i  have  xml  like  this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Job>
        <WSData  WSName="PersonData">
        <Name>Aghata</Name>
        <Id>1234567899</Id>     
        </WSData>
        <WSData " WSName="Standard">
            <RawData>

                    <PersonalData>
                        <Name>
                            Aghata
                        </Name>

                        <Identifier>
                            123456789
                        </Identifier>
                        <Number>
                            12345678900
                        </Number>
                    </PersonalData>

            </RawData>
        </WSData>
</Job>
```

AND   I  WANT  TO  WRITE  XSLT  WHICH  WILL  HELP  ME  COPY  wsdata  WITH
WSName  PersonData in   another  xml  ,   how  should  i  manage  this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieve this you can use `xsl:copy-of`. See the link or code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Job">
        <Job>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//WSData[@WSName='PersonData']"/>
        </Job>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression you want is `//WSData[@WSName='Standard']` which you can use in an select clause in `xsl:apply-templates`, or `xsl:copy-of` for example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//WSData[@WSName='PersonData']" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```